# jQuery Slideshow Using Timer Plugin - How to Change Slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making a jQuery slider (so cliche), and I'm having an issue getting the slide to change when you click one of the bullets in the controls. Other than that, it's fully functional. I found the jQuery timer plugin and swapped it out with the 'setInterval()' function I was using.

So, problem, I can't seem to figure out how to get the slide to change when you click on a bullet in the controls... I tried passing the clicked bullet value (slide#) to the timer function and that didn't work (the way I did it). I don't know much about methods or jQuery plugin formats, so this has proven difficult for me.

And the link on **my server** ***(working)***: http://www.horsepowerfreaks.com/plugins/responsiveSlider/demo.html

Here is the **jsFiddle** *(not working for some reason...)*: http://jsfiddle.net/derekfoulk/yUqKJ/

***Files:***

**Slider plugin** (where the issue is)
http://www.horsepowerfreaks.com/plugins/responsiveSlider/rSlider.jquery.js

**Stylesheet**
http://www.horsepowerfreaks.com/plugins/responsiveSlider/style.css

**Plugin Documentation/Demo:**
https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer
http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

**A portion of my attempt:**

```
/* Bullets - Here is my problem. This is not working the way I need it to.
Basically, when the user clicks a bullet, the slider should make the referenced
slide active and then reset the timer */

else if (action === "bullet"){
    // If user clicks on active bullet
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        // Play/Pause (timer)
        Slider.toggleGallery();
    }
    else {
        /* Change slide (by referencing the 'data-slide' attribute of the bullet,
        then find the slide using that same value for its 'data-slide' attribute
        and make it the active slide and reset the timer */
        imageId = $(this).attr("data-slide");
        $(".active",$controls).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        Slider.changeSlide(imageId);
    }
}
```

***...Further down the file...***

```
Slider = new (function() {
    var $galleryImages,
    $timeRemaining,
    incrementTime = options.pause,

    /* I am pretty sure this function needs to be fed the slide number that was selected
    when the user clicks a bullet. If it is the first run through, then the value of
    'imageId' should be '-1'. I would rather have the imageId value be set to '1'
    initially, but the configuration below is what worked for me... If I set the imageId
    to '0', numSlides to '$galleryImages.length' and the imageId inside the if statement
    to 0, then I get slide 2 for imageId 1, slide 3 for imageId 2, slide 4 for imageId 3,
    and slide 1 for imageId 4? If there is a way to have the active image (imageId)
    iterate '1,2,3,4' instead of '0,1,2,3' that would be awesome. */

    imageId = -1, // Which image is being shown
    updateTimer = function() {
        $galleryImages.eq(imageId).stop(true,true).removeClass("active");
        imageId++;
        console.log(imageId);
        var numSlides = $galleryImages.length - 1;
        if (imageId >= numSlides) {
            imageId = -1;
        }
        $galleryImages.eq(imageId).stop(true,false).addClass("active");
    },

    init = function() {
        $galleryImages = $(".slider").find('li');
        Slider.Timer = $.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true).once();
    };
    this.toggleGallery = function() {
        if (this.Timer.isActive) {
            this.Timer.pause();
            var remaining = this.Timer.remaining / 1000;
        }
        else {
            this.Timer.play();
        }
    };
    $(init);
});
```

Comment: I know there is an error in the console regarding the changeSlide()... I left it there after my attempts to show what I thought would be a step in the right direction...

Comment: Nobody? Okay, I'll post the answer when I get it figured out :)